# How to check if a result array element is present in another result array

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I have this code in my program:

```
<?php

session_start();
$_SESSION['user_id']=201102887;
$con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
if(!$con)
{
   die("not ok");
}
mysqli_select_db($con,"uoh");
$q = "SELECT * FROM courses
      INNER JOIN  transfer_student_courses
      ON          transfer_student_courses.course_number = courses.course_number
      INNER JOIN  transfered_courses
      ON          transfer_student_courses.sn = transfered_courses.sn 
      AND         transfer_student_courses.student_ID = " . $_SESSION['user_id'];
$result = mysqli_query($con , $q);
if($result){
   echo "<table>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<th>equivalent</th>";
   echo "</tr>";
   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row["equivalent"]. "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   } 
   echo "</table>";
}

mysqli_select_db($con,"uoh");
$q = "SELECT * FROM courses 
      LEFT JOIN  degree_plan
      ON         degree_plan.course_number = courses.course_number 
      LEFT JOIN  student_record
      ON         courses.course_number = student_record.course_number 
      AND        student_record.id = ". $_SESSION['user_id']."
      WHERE      degree_plan.major = 'COE'
      ORDER BY   term_no";

$result = mysqli_query($con , $q );
if($result){
   echo "<table>";
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<th>course</th>";
   echo "</tr>";

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
   {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row["code"]. "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
}
echo "</table>";

?>
```

I have two queries in this code, each of which give me a list of courses.
If a course appears in the first list, I do not want it to appear in the second list.

If you see the output of this code below, the first query gives me `MATH 101`, and the second query also gives me `MATH 101`.

I want `MATH 101` to not appear in the second course list because it also appears in the first list.

How can I write a function in PHP language to do that?

Output:

```
equivalent
MATH 101

course
PHYS 101
CHEM 101
PE 101
IAS 101
MATH 101
ENGL 101
```

Comment: You want something in your first list to not appear in the second. And what is the other query you have?

Comment: what is the course table primary key name id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, store all the `equivalent` courses in an array, say `$equivalent` array. And then in the second `while` loop use `in_array()` function to check if the course already got printed in the first table or not.

Here's the reference:

- [`in_array()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php)

So your code should be like this:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    $_SESSION['user_id']=201102887;
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
    if(!$con){
        die("not ok");
    }
    mysqli_select_db($con,"uoh");  
    $q = "SELECT * FROM courses INNER JOIN transfer_student_courses ON 
    transfer_student_courses.course_number=courses.course_number INNER
     JOIN transfered_courses ON transfer_student_courses.sn=transfered_courses.sn 
     AND transfer_student_courses.student_ID = " . $_SESSION['user_id'];
    $result = mysqli_query($con , $q) ;

    $equivalent = array();
    if($result){
        echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>equivalent</th>";
        echo "</tr>";
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            $equivalent[] = $row["equivalent"];
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["equivalent"]. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        } 
        echo "</table>";
    }

    mysqli_select_db($con,"uoh");  
    $q = "SELECT * FROM courses 
    LEFT JOIN degree_plan ON degree_plan.course_number= courses.course_number 
    LEFT JOIN student_record ON courses.course_number= student_record.course_number 
    AND student_record.id= ". $_SESSION['user_id']."
    WHERE degree_plan.major='COE' ORDER BY term_no";

    $result = mysqli_query($con , $q ) ;
    if($result){
       echo "<table>";
       echo "<tr>";
       echo "<th>course</th>";
       echo "</tr>";

        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
            if(in_array($row["code"], $equivalent)){
                continue;
            }
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>" . $row["code"]. "</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        } 
    }
    echo "</table>";   
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could load the results of the first query into an array, then when you are displaying the results for the second query, before you display anything check if the result exists in your array, if it does, skip it.

So after your first query:

```
$equivalent = array();  // Setup a blank array to store the results
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo "<tr>";
   echo "<td>" . $row["equivalent"]. "</td>";
   echo "</tr>";
   $equivalent[] = $row['equivalent'];  // Add the result into your array
}
```

Then in your courses portion of code:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   if ( ! in_array($row['code'], $equivalent ) ) 
   {
      echo "<tr>";
      echo "<td>" . $row["code"]. "</td>";
      echo "</tr>";
   }
}
```

This should stop the display of any entry that is in both result sets being displayed in the second.

HTH

Answer (score 0):

> Solution : in_array("word", $array)

Run a query get the result into an array :

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
   arr1[]=$row["code"];
}
```

For the second query run the query and add reults as follows:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    if (in_array($row[code], $arr1))
    {
      //don't add to array2
    }
    else
    {
      arr2[] = $row["code"];
    }
}
```

Then you may `echo` the elements as required.